# flavor префикс в имени апк при сборке релиза

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Подскажите как настроить градл так, чтобы когда я собираю релизный апк, к имени файла добавлялось бы имя flavor? в приложении имеется два flavor'a - demo и full
сейчас у меня к имени апк добавляется номер версии и билда

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                def outputFile = output.outputFile
                if (outputFile != null && outputFile.name.endsWith('.apk')) {
                    def fileName = "MyApp_v.${versionName}_b${versionCode}.apk"//outputFile.name.replace('.apk', "-${versionName}.apk")
                    output.outputFile = new File(outputFile.parent, fileName)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: ${productFlavor} если просто добавить?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja нет, градл ругается - неизвестная переменная

Comment: всё, разобрался, за это отвечает ${variant.productFlavors[0].name}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался сам, за это отвечает `${variant.productFlavors[0].name}`

Полный код:
(при сборке получится имя `MyApp_v2_b123_googleplay.apk`)

```
defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.example.app"
versionCode 123
versionName "2"

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def outputFile = output.outputFile
            if (outputFile != null && outputFile.name.endsWith('.apk')) {
                def fileName = "MyApp_v.${versionName}_b${versionCode}_${variant.productFlavors[0].name}.apk"
                output.outputFile = new File(outputFile.parent, fileName)
            }
        }
    }
}
productFlavors {
    googleplay{
        ...
    }

    someother{
        ...
    }
}
```